# Numbering page of an existing document

Tags: vb.net, itext

Using iTextSharp, I would like to get example or help in order to number each page of an existing PDF document using VB.net (Windows Form) in VB express 2010.

Comment: Would a c# example suffice?

Comment: Yes, it could help...

Answer (score 2):

As the OP indicated that a c# example also suffices:

The second pass in the [Webified iTextSharp Example](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/) [TwoPasses.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=TwoPasses) (after the comment "SECOND PASS, ADD THE HEADER") adds *Page **x** of **y*** (and a title *FOOBAR FILMFESTIVAL*) header to each document page.

The pivotal code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF);
using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream()) {
    // Create a stamper
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms2)) {
        // Loop over the pages and add a header to each page
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            GetHeaderTable(i, n).WriteSelectedRows(
              0, -1, 34, 803, stamper.GetOverContent(i)
            );
        }
    }
    // retrieve the result PDF in ms2.ToArray()
}
```

which uses the helper method `GetHeaderTable` which assembles the header text for a page:

```
public static PdfPTable GetHeaderTable(int x, int y) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.TotalWidth = 527;
    table.LockedWidth = true;
    table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = 20;
    table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
    table.AddCell("FOOBAR FILMFESTIVAL");
    table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    table.AddCell(string.Format("Page {0} of {1}", x, y));
    return table;
}
```