# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'

Tags: vb.net, keydown

Here is my code :

I have the form load function :

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
    RaiseEvent KeyDown(Me, e)
End Sub
```

I have the event declaration :

```
Event KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
```

And the function which should open MsgBox When control key is pressed :

```vb
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
End Sub
```

But I have this error :

> System.InvalidCastException : 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.EventArgs' en type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.'

That is the complete error message

So I do not know what should I do

Comment: Re "So i do not know what should i do" - this is very sad. Perhaps you should create appropriate KeyEventArgs object and use that? See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do here? Why would you forward the form load event arg to your key down event handler?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: I want to know when a specific keyboard touch is down and do an action therefore

Answer (score 0):

Set `Form.KeyPreview = True`

Also, your `Keys.Control` is the control modifier, you may be looking for `Keys.ControlKey`

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey Then MsgBox("test")
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3417466 If djv's answer solved the problem, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (Also, was your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391201/numbering-page-of-an-existing-document) answered satisfactorily?)